# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I have looked for other cases like this but none quite apply to me.... or if they do I don't understand how.

What I am trying to do is to filter through a 2D array (this):

```
blocks = [
[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ],

[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ],

[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ],

[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ],

[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ],

[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ],

[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ],

[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ],

[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ],

[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ]
```

and find out what the current part is. Sorry if my code is a bit sloppy, I am new to python. This is (part) of my code,

```
def drawBlock():
for blockL1 in blocks:
    for blokL2 in blocks:
        if blocks[blockL1[blockL2[1]]] == 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 255), Rect((blockL1 * 32, blockL2 *32), (32, 32)))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, Rect(i * 32, ))
        global blockL2
        blockL2 += 1
    global blockL1
    blockL1 += 1
```

Comment: Your blocks is actually a 3 dimensional array.  Remove the `[]` surrounding each `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple issues going on here.

The main problem being your use of the `for blank in blank_holder`.

When you write

```
for blockL1 in blocks:
```

its almost identical to writing

```
for ii in range(len(blocks)):
    blockL1 = blocks[ii]
    ...
```

meaning that blockL1 is not an integer, or an index of blocks.. it is an element of blocks!

its value would look like: `[  [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]  ]`

Which is a list of lists... where as `blocks` is a list of lists that contain lists... yeah

when you write

```
for blockL1 in blocks:
    for blockL2 in blocks:
```

the value of `blockL2` would be a single list `[0]`

assuming you want to look at the one value contained in `blockL2`, you can change:

```
if blocks[blockL1[blockL2[1]]] == 0:
```

to:

```
if blockL2[0] == 0: # the 1 index would go out of bounds for a list length 1
```

However this code looks like you need the indexed values of `blockL1` and `blockL2`, so I recommend you loop through lists of their indices (meaning `ints`)... not their elemnents

```
def drawBlock():
    for blockL1 in range(len(blocks)):
        for blockL2 in range(len(blockL1)):
            if blocks[blockL1[blockL2[0]]] == 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 255), Rect((blockL1 * 32, blockL2 *32), (32, 32)))
```

Hopefully this helps some!

Comment: Thanks! This actually kind of makes sense! I appreciate you trying to help me, because the first kind of loop I learned was javascript style, which makes it hard to envision in different styles. So you suggest that I use the code at the bottom? Thx!

Comment: @ETBCOR It realy depends on the style youre going for,.. but yes i suggest the bottom if the logic requires knowing the position of the current block in the main array.